# Number of cells in an RNN

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I have been reading about RNNs and I have some confusion between the number of timesteps and number of units in an RNN layer (which after searching for an answer) seems to be a common thing.
I understand that the idea behind using a RNN is to capture the relationship between every element in the sequence with other elements.
In an example of text classification with tweets padded to a length of 20 words,
the number of units in a layer -which I understand is the same as the number of timesteps-  should be equal to the length of the input sequence which is 20.
I also saw some examples that deals with the number of units as a hyperparameter to be tuned.
Which of these is correct?

[image]

This picture is from a course on coursera by Andrew Ng. The super script Tx indicates the number of  timesteps which is the same as the number of units in the network.

Answer (score 4):

The number of cells and sequence length are distinct concepts. I think the clearest way to demonstrate this is to just write out the equations. For instance, the simple Elman RNN has equations

$$
\begin{align}
a_t &= f_a\left(W_a x_t + U_a a_{t-1} + b_a\right) \\
y_t &= f_y\left(W_y a_t + b_y\right)
\end{align}
$$

where $a_t$ is the hidden state vector at time $t$, $y_t$ is the prediction at time $t$ and $x_t$ is the input at time $t$. Each $x_t$ is a vector with some number of features $k$, and the hidden state has some dimension $p$. So $W_a$ must have shape $p \times k$ for the matrix multiplication to work. Likewise, matrix $U_a$ must have shape $p\times p$ and the bias $b_a$ must have shape $p\times 1$. The functions $f_a, f_y$ are just the activation function(s) that you're using -- sigmoid or ReLU or any other activation.

If you wish to apply an RNN to a sequence, first initialize $a_0$ and then loop over the recurrence relation. In psuedocode, it looks something like this:

```
for t in 1 ... T:
    a[t] = f_a(x[t], a[t-1])
    y[t] = f_y(a[t])
```

where `f_a` and `f_y` apply the weights and biases as well as the non-linearity.

The *number of units* is $p$. It should be clear that you can change $p$ and the total number of time steps $T$ independently, because the recurrence relation allows us to carry out the prediction loop for as many steps as we wish -- as long as we can provide $x_t$.

We can do the same for the [lstm](/questions/tagged/lstm) and [gru](/questions/tagged/gru) networks.

- I've answered the same question for LSTM networks. [When computing parameters, why is dimensions of hidden-output state of an LSTM-cell assumed same as the number of LSTM-cell?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468927/when-computing-parameters-why-is-dimensions-of-hidden-output-state-of-an-lstm-c/470465#470465)
- I've also reproduced the GRU equations here [How many parameters are in a gated recurrent unit (GRU) recurrent neural network (RNN) layer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328926/how-many-parameters-are-in-a-gated-recurrent-unit-gru-recurrent-neural-network/328927#328927) for a different question.

Comment: Why would we need more units than the length of the sequence? And in such case, how is each sequence passed through the layer? Assume a sequence with 20 words and a layer with 10 units, the sequence is passed through the layer in two pieces with 10 words each. Is this correct?

Comment: And assume another case where the sequence is of 20 words and the layer has 30 units, is the sequence passed through the first 20 units then the next sequence comes in?

Comment: The descriptions in these comments are not correct because time and number of units are distinct concepts, as described in my answer. The dimension of the weight matrices does not reflect time. The concept of time is defined by the recurrence relation.

Comment: what do you mean by recurrence relation?

Comment: The value of $a_t$ depends on $a_{t-1}$ (and $x_t$, but dependence on $x_t$ is not a recurrence).

Comment: Alright. a  is the hidden state of timestep t. Does every cell has a hidden state?

Comment: What do you think? What is the dimension of $a_t$?

Comment: It seems like I have a big misunderstanding of RNNs. Do you have any resources that demonstrates what happens exactly in matrix forms and all the math that goes in it?

Comment: David Lay's *Linear Algebra and its Applications* is a serviceable undergraduate textbook. It will get you started with matrix arithmetic.

Comment: A little over a year later, I understand how RNNs work. I used to confuse the number of cells with number of timesteps. I now understand that a sequence of inputs goes through the cell repeatedly and each time step has its own hidden state but has shared weights with all other time steps.
I want to thank you @Sycorax for your patience.